# Error using amsart with algorithmic[x]

Tags: amsart, algorithmicx

I use the `algorithm` and `algorithmicx` packages to type algorithms in a paper and my main document class is `amsart`. All is well until I try to use `\listofalgorithms`. This returns a variety of error messages, some of which I've been able to work around thanks to other threads on this website. I am now stuck at the following and here is a (very) minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\let\chapter\section               % Conflict fix found on this site.
\usepackage[norelsize]{algorithm}  % [norelsize] fixes another conflict.

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms                  % This is the problematic command.
\end{document}
```

This MWE uses `algorithmic` but the same behavior occurs with `algorithmicx`.
Running this through pdflatex returns the error

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.7 \listofalgorithms
```

I'm hoping someone has a hint as to how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: I made an update to my answer changing some settings to make the list of algorithms behave more as the list of figures, or tables.

Comment: `algorithm` knows the options `plain`, `ruled` and `boxed` for the appearance of algorithms; `nothing`, `part`, `chapter`, `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection` for their numbering; any other option is taken as the algorithm name (for a different language than English, for instance).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I was doing the same. I'm currently working with `\def\l@algorithm{\@tocline{1}{0pt}{1pc}{2.1em}{}}` which seems to be compact and looks like the table of contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some redefinitions are necessary (notice that I didn't use the `norelsize` option):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\let\chapter\section               % Conflict fix found on this site.
\usepackage{algorithm}  % [norelsize] fixes another conflict.

\makeatletter
\def\listofalgorithms{\@starttoc{loa}\listalgorithmname}
\def\l@algorithm{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{1.9em}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{test algorithm one}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{test algorithm two}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Indeed using `norelsize` changed "List of Algorithms" to "List of Norelsizes" in my case!!! Now I just have to tweak the appearance of the list.